# $\sigma$-algebra over a set of measures

Tags: probability-theory, ergodic-theory

In Theorem 6.6 of the book *Probability Theory* by Varadhan, he proved the existence of a probability measure over a set $M_e$ of ergodic measures. The context is as follows.

Let $(\Omega,\mathcal{F})$ be a complete separable metric space with its Borel sets. And let $T:\Omega \to \Omega$ be a measurable map. A probability measure $P$ is invariant (with respect to $T$) if $$P[T^{-1}(A)]=P[A]$$ for every $A \in \mathcal{F}$. And here comes the theorem.

> **Theorem 6.6.** For any invariant measure $P$, there is a probability measure $\mu_P$ on the set $M_e$ of ergodic measures such that $$P=\int_{M_e}Q\mu_P(dQ).$$

I think the set $M_e$ in this theorem is not necessarily countable. For an existence of probability measure on $M_e$, we should first have a $\sigma$-algebra on $M_e$. How is it defined?

Thanks for any comment!

Comment: You probably forgot to complete the equation for $\int_{M_e} Q\mu_p(dQ)$.

Comment: @Iwassuspendedfortalking Thanks for your remind. I have corrected it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$, the natural sigma-algebra $\mathcal D$ on the set $\Delta$ of probability measures on $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$ is defined as follows. For each $A \in \mathcal F$, let $X_A: \Delta \to \mathbb R$ be the function defined by $X_A(P) = P(A)$. Define $\mathcal D$ to be the smallest sigma-algebra on $\Delta$ that makes every member of $\{X_A: A \in \mathcal F\}$ measurable (we assume, as is standard, that $\mathbb R$ is equipped with its Borel sigma-algebra). Equivalently, $\mathcal D$ is the sigma-algebra generated by $\{X_A^{-1}(B): A \in \mathcal F, B \subseteq \mathbb R \ \text{Borel}\}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!